# How can I save the text with line breaks or spaces between the rows?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, model-view-controller, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a memo field in a popup dialog and there is a Save button.

If I write a text with more than 1 rows, than the text will pasted together with no space or line break.

[image: example]

How can I save the text with line breaks or spaces between the rows (in the textarea)?

TextArea:

```
<div class="k-edit-form-container"  style="margin-top: 8px;">
    <textarea class="k-textbox" id="valueExplenation" multiple="multiple" />
</div>
```

Button:

```
<a role="button" id="saveExplenation" class="" href="#" onclick="saveValue($('#valueExplenation').val());">Save</a>
```

Push the data to the function in the controller:

```
function saveValue(value) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: host + "/api/home/saveValue/" + myId + "/" + value,
        data: value,
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        cache: false
    })
```

The header of the GET-function

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/home/saveValue/{id:long}/{value}")]
public bool SaveValue(long id, string value)
{
...
```

Comment: Have you looked at this with a debugger? I'm pretty sure you will find some sort of delimiter there. One you figure it out, you can either split on the delimiter (and deal with the string collection) or replace the delimiter with one you're happy with

Answer (score 0):

You should really be POSTing data like this. That is what POST is for. GET is for passing simple variables through in order to GET a response, or to allow caching of requests. POST is for sending data and has built in support from the browsers (like not allowing someone to refresh and POST again without warning them)

The textarea will send data through as it appears in the textarea (with `\n` for linebreaks). If you want to display that data, you can replace the line breaks with `<br />` tags. With php it's `<?php echo nl2br($string);?>`, with javascript it would be somethign like `document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = string.replaceAll("\n","<br />")`